# Getting checklist to show all selected items (rather than whichever item is selected first)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datatables

I have a data table with checkboxes that correspond to each row. Ideally when you click on a checkbox it appends that row's contents into a "Favorites List". But what's happening is that whichever checkbox I click is the only one that gets displayed in the list.

I get *why* only the first item is shown (`favesArr[0]`), but what I want to know is `how to get the List to show all of the items that are selected.` I left out the HTML file in this question, so if you'd like to see it then let me know.

[Here's a screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPfJM.png) that shows my browser.

#### JS sample:

```
import JSONfile from '../../../public/JSONfile.json';

loadTableData() {
    $.noConflict();
    let tableRes = JSONfile.d.results.filter(function(val) { 
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {

      return {
        "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
        "Titles": obj.File.Name,
        "Categories": obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
          return val.Label;
        }).join(";"),
        // "Blank": ''
        }

      });

$('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        { data: "Titles" }, // populates col-2 column with docs
        { data: "Categories" } // hidden col-3 categories
      ],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          data: "Path",
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            return $('<a>')
              .attr({target: "_blank", href: row.Path})
              .text(data)
              .wrap('<div></div>')
              .parent()
              .html();
          },
          targets: 0
        },
        { searchable: true, targets: [1], visible: false },
      ],
      data: tableRes,
      language: { searchPlaceholder: "Search All Documents" },
      responsive: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollY: 600,
      select: {
        selector: "td:first-child",
        style: "os"
      },
      stateSave: true
    });

    ($("#km-table-id tbody tr")).append($("<input />", {"type": "checkbox"}).addClass("checkbox-class"));

    const $table = $("#km-table-id")

    let table = $table.DataTable();
    let favesArr = [];

    $table.on("click", ".checkbox-class", function(e) {
      let data = table.row(this.parentNode).data(),
      checked = $(this).is(":checked"),
      dataIndex = favesArr.indexOf(data);
      if (checked) {
        if (dataIndex === -1) {
          favesArr.push(data); // add item
        }
      } else {
        if (dataIndex > -1) {
          favesArr.splice(dataIndex, 1); // remove item
        }
      }     

      // let arrOfTitles = favesArr;
      // let uniqueTitles = [];
      // $.each(arrOfTitles, function(e, el) {
      //   if ($.inArray(el, uniqueTitles) === -1) uniqueTitles.push(el);
      // });

      $(".populate-faves").append(JSON.stringify(favesArr[0].Titles) + '<br/>'); /////// This is the line that's bugging me


      console.log(favesArr); ///// does show whichever document (obj) is selected
    });


  } // ------------------ loadTableData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get one line for each entry in the `favesArr`, you could first remove all previous entries (`$(".populate-faves").empty();`) and then add one entry for each favorite like this:

```
for (var i=0;i<favesArr.length;i++) {
    $(".populate-faves").append(JSON.stringify(favesArr[i].Titles) + '<br/>');
}
```

There are, of course, many ways more elegant to go about this, but this would be the most intuitive way coming from were you are now, i think.

Comment: That did it! That was much more concise than I thought it was going to be. Thanks a ton!